# How many wives did Adam have?

Tags: genesis, adam-and-eve, extra-biblical, legend

Genesis 1:26 says:

> 26 Then God said, “And now we will make human beings; they will be like us and resemble us. They will have power over the fish, the birds, and all animals, domestic and wild, large and small.” 27 So God created human beings, making them to be like himself. He created them male and female, 28 blessed them, and said, “Have many children, so that your descendants will live all over the earth and bring it under their control. I am putting you in charge of the fish, the birds, and all the wild animals.

Now I wonder why did God put Adam to sleep to make him another wife in Genesis 2:18 which says:

> 18 Then the Lord God said, “It is not good for the man to live alone. I will make a suitable companion to help him.” 19 So he took some soil from the ground and formed all the animals and all the birds. Then he brought them to the man to see what he would name them; and that is how they all got their names. 20 So the man named all the birds and all the animals; but not one of them was a suitable companion to help him.
>
> 21 Then the Lord God made the man fall into a deep sleep, and while he was sleeping, he took out one of the man's ribs and closed up the flesh. 22 He formed a woman out of the rib and brought her to him. 23 Then the man said,

“At last, here is one of my own kind — Bone taken from my bone, and flesh from my flesh. ‘Woman’ is her name because she was taken out of man.”

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What would make a good answer to this question? Are you interested in learning more about traditions which say Adam had multiple wives? Are you interested in interpretations which attempt to reconcile the apparent contradiction here? Are you interested in scholarly sources which attempt to determine the intent of Genesis' authors and/or editors?

Answer (score 10):

Adam had only ONE wife, Eve.  The simple answer is that Genesis chapter 1 is like an overview of the events of creation.  It can be seen as the introduction. Then Genesis chapter 2 goes on to provide the detail of the events of the sixth day of creation.

In Chapter 1 we are told that God, after creating all the animals, created man and woman.  In Chapter 2 we get the detail on how God created man and woman. After God created the animals from the elements of the earth he brought them to Adam so he could name them.  Later, God creates Eve out of one of Adam’s ribs.

> Genesis 1:1 says, “In the beginning, God created the heavens and the earth.” Later, in Genesis 2:4, it seems that a second, different story of creation begins. The idea of two differing creation accounts is a common misinterpretation of these two passages which, in fact, describe the same creation event. They do not disagree as to the order in which things were created and do not contradict one another. Genesis 1 describes the “six days of creation” (and a seventh day of rest), Genesis 2 covers only one day of that creation week—the sixth day—and there is no contradiction.
>
> In Genesis 2, the author steps back in the temporal sequence to the sixth day, when God made man. In the first chapter, the author of Genesis presents the creation of man on the sixth day as the culmination or high point of creation. Then, in the second chapter, the author gives greater detail regarding the creation of man.  Source: [Why are there two different Creation accounts in Genesis chapters 1-2?](https://www.gotquestions.org/two-Creation-accounts.html)

One man and one woman, one husband and one wife, whom God blessed and told to procreate and fill the Earth.

Answer (score 5):

According to Scriptures, the only wife that Adam had was Eve.

Notwithstanding the biblical sources, that Adam had only one wife, there is a legend that Adam had a Wife named [Lilith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilith).

> **Lilith** is the most notorious demon in Jewish tradition. In some sources, she is conceived of as the original woman, created even before Eve, and she is often presented as a thief of newborn infants. Lilith means “the night,” and she embodies the emotional and spiritual aspects of darkness: terror, sensuality, and unbridled freedom. More recently, she has come to represent the freedom of feminist women who no longer want to be “good girls.”
>
> **Biblical and Talmudic Tales of Lilith**
>
> The story of Lilith originated in the ancient Near East, where a wilderness spirit known as the “dark maid” appears in the Sumerian myth “The descent of Inanna” (circa 3000 BCE). Another reference appears in a tablet from the seventh century BCE found at Arslan Tash, Syria which contains the inscription: “O flyer in a dark chamber, go away at once, O Lili!”
>
> Lilith later made her way into Israelite tradition, possibly even into the Bible. Isaiah 34:14, describing an inhospitable wilderness, tells us: “There goat-demons shall greet each other, and there the lilit shall find rest.” Some believe this word “lilit” is a reference to a night owl, and others say it is indeed a reference to the demon Lilith. A magical bowl from the first century CE, written in Hebrew, reads:” Designated is this bowl for the sealing of the house of this Geyonai bar Mamai, that there flee from him the evil Lilith…” Ancient images of Lilith which show her hands bound appear to be a form of visual magic for containing her.
>
> In the Talmud, Lilith becomes not only a spirit of darkness,but also a figure of uncontrolled sexuality. The Babylonian Talmud (Shabbat151a) says: “It is forbidden for a man to sleep alone in a house, lest Lilith get hold of him.” Lilith is said to fertilize herself with male sperm to give birth to other demons.
>
> Lilith as Escaped Wife
>
> In Genesis Rabbah, we encounter a brief midrash that claims that Adam had a first wife before Eve. This interpretation arises from the two creation stories of Genesis: In Genesis 1, man and woman are created at the same time, while in Genesis 2 Adam precedes Eve. The rabbinic tale suggests that the first creation story is a different creation, in which Adam has a wife made, like him, from the earth. For some reason this marriage doesn’t work out, and so God makes Adam a second wife, Eve. - [Lilith, Lady Flying in Darkness](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/lilith-lady-flying-in-darkness/)

**As Sacred Scriptures admit that Adam had only one Wife, there is no reason to believe otherwise and put stock into old legends, tales or myths.**

> There are legends that Adam had a wife before Eve who was named Lilith, but this is not found in the Bible. The legends vary significantly, but they all essentially agree that Lilith left Adam because she did not want to submit to him. According to the legends, Lilith was an evil, wicked woman who committed adultery with Satan and produced a race of evil creatures. None of this is true. There is no biblical basis whatsoever for these concepts. There is no one in the Bible named Lilith.
>
> Another commonly used support for Lilith is the differing Creation accounts in Genesis chapters 1-2. Some claim that the woman in Genesis 1 was Lilith, with the woman in Genesis 2 being Eve. This is completely ludicrous. Rather, Genesis chapter 2 is a "closer look" at the creation of Adam and Eve as recorded in Genesis chapter 1. The Bible specifically says that Adam and Eve were the first human beings ever created (Genesis 1:26-28; 2:18-25). This "Lilith" myth is popular in some radical feminist movements because Lilith is an example of a woman refusing to submit to male headship. While there are myths outside of the Word of God regarding Lilith, her complete absence from Scripture demonstrates that she is nothing more than a myth. - [How many wives did Adam have?](https://www.quora.com/How-many-wives-did-Adam-have)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to understand Genisis 1 and 2 as the process of creation. You envision it, tell about it and then you translate the words into action by actually making it happen.

Eve was the only woman God created for Adam. He made them male an female, in his own image and likeness hence the ability to create their own creation was passed on to them from their creator. She was his only wife. There was no other wife. They both enjoy the gift of being God creatures, with Godly personalities and traits thus enjoyed the privilege of having dominion over all birds, fish and beasts.Not only that, they also were blessed with the ability to replenish the earth with more human beings.

The Lilith Myth is just a description of the darker side of Eve that probably got them both into trouble with their creator. She is a creature of man and not of God.

Answer (score 0):

Lilith is just a myth. God created a man and  woman, by then they were no people on earth. which proves that it's just an evil spirit and nothing else.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange. When you have a moment, please take the Christianity Stack tour to learn more about us: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour This is how we are different to other sites: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/26900. See [my comment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/69180/how-many-wives-did-adam-have#comment198649_691809) for some ideas about what a good answer to this question might include.

Comment: This is the beginning of a good answer; if you'll offer [some support for this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) it will be a complete answer.

Answer (score -2):

To be fair, this depends wholly on what text you observe. If you believe the Greek translation, then 1. If you believe the original text, there were 3 (each corresponding to Hebrew letters and their meanings)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "If you believe the original text, there were 3 (each corresponding to Hebrew letters and their meanings)" What is this supposed to mean???